# Morphological operation which should have to use

Tags: image-processing, mathematical-morphology

For discontinuous dotted text, to make it plain continuous text ,which morphological operation have to be done?
dilation or opening?

Comment: Dilation. Opening erodes first.

Comment: I think, in general, texts on morphology expect the foreground (i.e. the thing you are interested in, such as the letters in your example) to be **white** on a **black** background. So, if you wanted to increase the size of and fill gaps in the text you would need to dilate. However, if your text is black on a white background (i.e. inverted vis-à-vis the literature), then you would actually need to erode (or alternatively, invert and dilate and re-invert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing would be the most appropriated. A dilation will connect the dots but deform a lot the shape. An opening will erase every thin structures, what you definitely do not want.